# Google Map React not appearing

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the `google-map-react`, but when I try to render it, nothing appears. Am I missing something?

```
import GoogleMap from 'google-map-react';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GMaps extends Component {



static defaultProps = {
    center: {lat: 59.95, lng: 30.33},
    zoom: 11
  };

render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <GoogleMap
       style={{width: "100%", height: "500"}}
       defaultCenter={this.props.center}
       defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
     />
   </div>
  )
} 


}
```

Comment: Works well here https://jsbin.com/xoqogolake/1/edit?js,console,output. Do you get any error. How are you rendering it

Comment: I do not get any errors.

Comment: Yes this works, any idea how to get the users current location?

Comment: make sure to clear float if you have any float/absolute positioning

Answer (score 6):

Assigning height and width to the container div fill, will fix the issue

```
<div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
<GoogleMapReact
   defaultCenter={this.props.center}
   defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
 />
</div>
```

as mentioned in getting-started: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you are rendering the app correctly.

See this working example: [`Codepen`](http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/pejXLM?editors=1010)

Comment: If the component is a default export , using GoogleMapReact or GoogleMap doesnt effect. Its only when the component is a named export that the name matters

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri you are correct. I have added this because I was not importing it in codepen and I had to use the default name. I have updated my answer to remove unrelevant information.

Comment: Yes this works, any idea how to get the users current location?

Comment: @joethemow You can get users current location using geolocation. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation