# react-native-maps@0.29.3: Android - Empty map

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

This is the result

[image]

I'm trying to add react-native-maps in my react-native. but when I add this library & link to my app then I'll run-android that successfully run that app but when app completely render it show an empty map. how to solve that problem?

Comment: react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.65.1 => 0.65.1

Anyone have a react-native-maps project with this version of react-native? I want to see the configuration in the android and IOS source files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Map React not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525595/google-map-react-not-appearing)

Answer (score 0):

If you place google map Api than make sure you have also enable android capabilities in you google map Api.

To enable google map capabilities:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com
2. From left menu select Apis and services > Library
3. search for Map sdk for android. and navigate to map sdk for android page
4. press enable button to enable map sdk for android

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. I already had to activate google maps sdk for android in the project, I also generated an api key for my project. However I have no error in the console. The only real problem is that the map is simply not displayed.