# I am unable to load google maps into my react application . It is not showing anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, bootstrap-4, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone help me to solve the problem . I have tried to load google maps into my react application but it is showing a blank screen . How can i add it to my React app . Please Help !!!

```
    import React from 'react'
    import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react'

    function Mapp() {

    const coordinates = {lat : 0 , lng : 0 }

    return (
    <div className = 'map__container'\>
    <GoogleMapReact
    bootstrapURLKeys = {{key:'AIzaSyDX73JHrCuz5VcmSZgRLrdovodtcFNTku8'}}
    defaultCenter={coordinates}
    center = { coordinates }
    defaultZoom  = {14}  
    margin = {\[50,50,50,50\]}  
    onChange = {''}
    >

    </GoogleMapReact>
    
    </div>

)
}

export default Mapp ;
```

Comment: The code shown produces syntax errors.  Is your browser or development environment not reporting those errors?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you see any errors in the console? Have you checked the basic example they provide [in the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440537/i-am-unable-to-load-google-maps-into-my-react-application-it-is-not-showing-an) to see if you've followed it correctly? Particularly note the `Important!` comment in that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `width` and `height` for the wrapper div.. it is mentioned in the [npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) itself

> My map doesn't appear! Make sure the container element has width and
> height. The map will try to fill the parent container, but if the
> container has no size, the map will collapse to 0 width / height. This
> is not a requirement for google-map-react, its a requirement for
> google-maps in general.

```
   <div width='360px' height='360px' className = 'map__container'\>
     <GoogleMapReact
       bootstrapURLKeys = {{key:'AIzaSyDX73JHrCuz5VcmSZgRLrdovodtcFNTku8'}}
       defaultCenter={coordinates}
       center = { coordinates }
       defaultZoom  = {14}  
       margin = {\[50,50,50,50\]}  
      onChange = {''}
     />    
   </div>
```

Comment: There is an [outstanding duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525595/google-map-react-not-appearing) for this.